# Java - JFrame, JPanel and Components Won't show

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have this activity that includes GUI. This activity includes inputting the length and width, x and y (location of the shape in the canvas) and the button which chooses the shape, rectangle or circle. After clicking the button, it then accept the length, width, x and y inside the textfield.

After fiddling with the GUI code manually, the JPanels and JFrames won't show even after setting the size, just pure blank.

I was expecting to put the canvas on the left and the labels, textfields and buttons on the right. What am I doing wrong? I'm still at the early part of the program just aesthetic. Thank you.

```
public class Problem02{
    Problem02(){
        JFrame framer = new JFrame("Problem 02");
        framer.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        framer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel LPanel = new  JPanel();
        JPanel RPanel = new JPanel();
        Canvas canvasses = new Canvas();Label XLabel = new Label("X");
        JLabel YLabel = new JLabel("Y");
        JLabel WidthLabel = new JLabel("Width");
        JLabel LengthLabel = new JLabel("Length");
        JButton RectangleButton = new JButton("Rectangle");
        JButton CircleButton = new JButton("Circle");
        JTextField XText = new JTextField("");
        JTextField YText = new JTextField("");
        JTextField WidthText = new JTextField("");
        JTextField LengthText = new JTextField("");

        framer.add(LPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        framer.add(RPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        LPanel.add(canvasses);
        RPanel.add(XLabel);
        RPanel.add(XText);
        RPanel.add(YLabel);
        RPanel.add(YText);
        RPanel.add(WidthLabel);
        RPanel.add(WidthText);
        RPanel.add(LengthLabel);
        RPanel.add(LengthText);
        RPanel.add(RectangleButton);
        RPanel.add(CircleButton);

        framer.setSize(500,500);
        framer.setTitle("Problem 02");
        framer.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     new Problem02();

    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Comment: put setVisible(true) in your main method like this. new Problem02.setVisible(true);

Comment: also you should add your JPanel to your JFrame to see added components. use : framer.add(xPanel);

Comment: I already did framer.add(LPanel); and framer.add(RPanel);

Comment: you don't need framer at all because your class extends JFrame. just call add(xPanel) in your constructor, and try to call setVisible in your main method. update your question with new changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're extending from JFrame PLUS you're using a JFrame variable (framer)... you add all the components to the variable, but you don't show `framer`, you show `this`.

Do not extend JFrame, an change the last lines to

```
    framer.setSize(500,500);
    framer.setTitle("Problem 02");
    framer.setVisible(true);
```

Plus, PLEASE, stick to naming conventions: lowercase letters for variables, you even trick StackOverflows text highlighting parser ;-)

Comment: Thank you! By the way, pretty new to StackOverflow, can I ask about layouts here in this comment? I wanted the canvas to appear on the left and the buttons on the right but how can I do it? FlowLayout was the only layout the teacher taught us about and it only centers the buttons and I cna't see the canvas.

Comment: Theres lots of good layout tutorials out there. Instead of FlowLayout you could use BorderLayout, and the lines `framer.add(LPanel);` should be changed to `     framer.add(LPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    framer.add(RPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);`
Or you can set one to `CENTER` too.

Comment: I did what you said about the East and West BorderLayout and changed the framer.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); to framer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());. Is the canvas supposed to be grey? How can I make the canvas fit the side of the panel kinda like a screen? I want the whole left panel to be canvas.

Answer (score 0):

you can leave Problem02 extended from Jframe like you did but then you don't have to use object frame and instead you can do that
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

and don't forget this
        this.getContentPane().add(RPanel);
        this.getContentPane().add(LPanel);

Comment: I've googled about the getContentPane(); but the definitions are too textbook. What are the purpose for it though?

Comment: Jframe is like a bag and you put all your GUI elements on it this method is responsible to do that